# What is this function statement?

Tags: javascript

What does this do? Is this something like an empty function? Can't find any information on this, in what use case this is used?

```js
(() => {
 console.log("test");
})
```

Comment: It doesn't really do anything. It creates a function, but it never calls it, and the function cannot subsequently be referenced. It's pretty much useless code.

Comment: This is a 
Arrow function

Comment: @Pointy I have seen this somewhere before, but whenever I run it, it doesn't do anything

Comment: It technically can be referenced...by using `();`, but that seems really pointless.

Comment: @Toby I know this is an arrow function but thats not the information I want to find out

Comment: @disinfor it *could* but that's not what was posted in the question.\

Comment: @z0nk not doing anything is pretty much what I meant. It is not useful code.

Comment: @Pointy Oh...I agree. The duplicate is the info I think OP needs.

Comment: @Pointy is there way to run it somehow tho? Is this totally useless and should I forget about it?

Comment: "What does it do?" It prints out test into the console.

Comment: If you posted an *actual* example from some context where you've seen the code, that would be helpful.

Comment: @Toby no it does not.

Comment: @Pointy, if you invoke it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it had another set of parenthesis at the end, it would be a self executing function

```js
(() => {
 console.log("test");
})()
```

but as is, it does nothing.